# How to use a component instead of html as content for the slots of another component in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to use the **outer** component expanding in it an **inner** one instead of html content so the **outer** could parse content of the **inner** with slot's logic.

Here is some code:

**outer.component.html**

```
<button>
  <ng-content select="h1"></ng-content>
</button>
<button>
  <ng-content select="h2"></ng-content>
</button>
<button>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

This is our **outer** component which is expecting to have `<h1>` `<h2>` tags and another content expanded in it when used.

**inner.component.html**

```
<h1>h1</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
```

This is **inner** component which actually has `<h1>` `<h2>` tags and `<h3>` tag as another content for the **outer** one.

And now that's how we're gonna use it:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-outer>
  <app-inner></app-inner>
</app-outer>
```

In this case we get two first empty buttons and third button has whole **inner** component with it's content. So the behavior I expect if like if I'd do it like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-outer>
  <h1>h1</h1>
  <h2>h2</h2>
  <h3>h3</h3>
</app-outer>
```

then each button in `outer.component` would have one `h` tag what we need in the example.

So how can I tell the **outer** component to cover the **inner** component the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23233 this couldn't be solved this way.

The one way to solve it is to use the **outer** component right in the **inner** component:

**outer.component.html** - stays unchanged

**inner.component.html**

```
<app-outer>
  <h1>h1</h1>
  <h2>h2</h2>
  <h3>h3</h3>
</app-outer>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-inner></app-inner>
```